# How to find each property of object knowing only attr value

Tags: javascript

I have associated array:

```
[
    {
        "attr_1":"value 1_1",
        "attr_2":"value 2_1",
        "attr_3":"value 3_1"
    },
    {
        "attr_1":"value 2_1",
        "attr_2":"value 2_2",
        "attr_3":"value 2_3"
    },
    {
        "attr_1":"value 1_1",
        "attr_2":"value 3_2",
        "attr_3":"value 3_3"
    }
]
```

And I need to get full object, by requesting 'value 1_1', for example. After request I want to see Object 1 and Object 3. I suppose that i need hash, but i don't know how :(

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect case for Array.filter!

```
yourArray.filter( function(elem) {
  // Loop attr_1, attr_2, attr_3
  for ( var i in elem ) {
    if ( elem[i] == 'value 1_1' ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Array.filter is native in all the browser but not on IE8 and below.
In that case you have to include this polyfill

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Mozilla Foundation http://www.mozilla.org/
 * This code is available under the terms of the MIT License
 */
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun != "function") {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var res = [];
        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this) {
                var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
                if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this)) {
                    res.push(val);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```

More info:
http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-array-object/array-filter

Comment: Hm, something strange happens. If I bind filter it returns properties, but if I filter in console it returns objects which have this property.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem! Check this http://jsfiddle.net/UCc4V/ it correctly returns the matching objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore):

```
list = [
    {
        "attr_1":"value 1_1",
        "attr_2":"value 2_1",
        "attr_3":"value 3_1"
    },
    {
        "attr_1":"value 2_1",
        "attr_2":"value 2_2",
        "attr_3":"value 2_3"
    },
    {
        "attr_1":"value 1_1",
        "attr_2":"value 3_2",
        "attr_3":"value 3_3"
    }
]

query = "value 1_1"

results = _(list).filter(function(elem) {
   return _(_(elem).values()).include(query)
})

console.log(results)
```

As opposed to raw javascript, this implementation takes into account all subtle details like own/non-own object properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(arr, value) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
       for (var k in arr[i]) {
           if (arr[i][k] === value) ret.push(arr[i]);
       }
    }
    return ret;
}
```